# using onBackPressed() with backward compatibility

Tags: android, sdk

I want to use onBackPressed() method and still want to provide support for Android SDK before 2.0.
onBackPressed() is introduced in Android SDK 2.0. but how to do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using onKeyDown;

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

          // Your Code Here

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may capture a key event and check for the back key. On your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And write the goBack method to go where you need.

More at: [Android - onBackPressed() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Answer --->
http://apachejava.blogspot.com/2011/01/backward-compatibility-using.html

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // This will be called either automatically for you on 2.0
    // or later, or by the code above on earlier versions of the
    // platform.
    return;
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work. 2 things... One, android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is not available on Android 1.5. Two, you need to call super.onBackPressed() else the back button does not work. Calling super.onBackPressed() will not be found under Android 1.5 device and return an error.

Comment: This is not my code sample. I got it from android developers official blog spot.