# onKeyDown() or onBackPressed()

Tags: android, back-button

I want to implement the back button functionality in my application. In application whenever  I'm clicking on back button in middle my control is going to login page directly, so can someone tell me where to override `onKeyDown()` or `onBackPressed()` methods?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.e("back key pressed","Back key pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

because I'm writing this inside onCreate and outside onCreate also, but it's not working ......

Comment: In general, methods like `onKeyDown()` ,or `onBackPressed()` should be override(you can take advantage of IDE,i.e, Eclipse, to do so beautifully), so they should be out of `onCreate()`. Can you explain your problem exactly? What's wrong?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558613/571353

Comment: add @Override above the function ... ???

Answer (score 12):

Depends on whether or not you want to support pre-Android 2.0 phones. The `onBackPressed()` method was added to Android 2.0 (API 5).

You may want to read this post on the Android Developer blog for details:

> http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: thanku man but where to write this method ????because i am trying to write this method inside onCreate and out side onCreate also but still control is not going inside the method can you help me out by simple answer???

Answer (score 5):

see below code. write outside the onCreate

```
  @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
  {  
         //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
         if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
         {  

                Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, RequiredActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent); 

         }  
         return true;  
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can override that back button

```
public void onBackPressed() {

     Intent start = new Intent(currentclassname.this,which activity u want.class);
        startActivity(start);
        finishActivity(0);
        }
```

By this you can move on any activity. This is very easy and simple way

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is about removing the login activity from the history stack.

Execute finish(); in your login activity when you start any other activity from that

Comment: 3-05 14:13:56.327: W/KeyCharacterMap(374): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: HELLO friends my control is not coming inside OnBack method ?can any body help regrading this ????

Comment: Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), MyGroup.class);
  TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
  parentActivity.startChildActivity("Add contacts", edit);