# Difference between onKeyDown() and onBackPressed()

Tags: android, onkeydown, onbackpressed

I'm confused about the usage of `onKeyDown()` and `onBackPressed()`.
Are both of these overriding methods the same in functionality & usage?
If not so, then what's the correct usage for both?

You might be referring to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566315/onkeydown-or-onbackpressed), which asks for place of implementation, but I'm asking for why and when rather then where.

Comment: @Hexfire SIR!!..you have flagged it as  duplicate referring to question here,which asks for place of implementation but i'm asking for why and when rather then where

Comment: @xamMTS I retracted flag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`onKeyDown()` can be used for any hardware key on your `Android` device, that can be the power button, back button, or volume button.

`onBackPressed()` is only called when the back button is pressed.

Here are the differences:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // back was pressed
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
      // volume up was pressed
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // back was pressed
}
```

See a full list of `KeyCode`s here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

As you can see, it's easier to implement `onBackPressed()` if you want to detect a back press.