# Overriding onBackPressed() does not disable back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I've an Activity that extends `AppCompatActivity`.

I tried to disable back button like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I get the `Toast` which is good sign, but bad sign is, that it finishes activity and goes to the previous one (I'd like to avoid that).

Comment: why don't simply hide the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **`onBackPressed`** then remove  [**`onKeyDown`**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for now. Read [**`onKeyDown() or onBackPressed()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566315/onkeydown-or-onbackpressed).

**FYI**

Remove this method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: aren't they doing that alread?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I have edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Override the **onBackPressed** in the **Activity**:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        backButtonHandler();
        return;
    }
```

Write your code **within the method called** in onBackPressed()

```
 public void backButtonHandler() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```