# clean stack and exit app onBackPressed() 

Tags: android, stack

basically my app has a loginScreen and once logged u can go through many activities. when i press the home button the app goes in background and if the user doesnt open it within a certain amount of time, the users session closes and u return to the loginScreen. now the problem is that if i want to close the app from the loginScreen once my session has expired i press the back key and it should close but it doesnt. it brings me to the previous element in the stack.

the wired thing is that on all onBackPressed() methods and when ever i started new intents i always use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
and on the loginScreen onBackPressed() i call `finish()`
but it doesnt work. anyone know why? and how do i solve this problem.

Thanks for the help!!!

code snippets
in many activities:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mpButtonClick.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuPagina.class); 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        startActivity(intent); 
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
```

in the loginActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        LoginActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: edited it with some code

Comment: This may be completely wrong and idiotic on my part but, does it matter that super.onBackPressed(); is happening before you clear the intent / finish?

Comment: no as the javadoc says "The default implementation simply finishes the current activity"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this two way:

1. kill app by using `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` on back press.

for this you need to add below permission on manifest.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

2 .  use static boolean 'isKill' variable with default false and every time set false in login activity oncreate() method.

set isKill value true in login activity onBackPress() method.

And then write below code in every activity onResume() method

```
if(isKill)
{
    finish();
}
```

Comment: the first method is brutal and quick to use. i've tried it but unfortunatly it doesnt work....i'll try the second method and i'll let u know.

Comment: I forget to mention that first method only exit application if only one Activity on Stack, So second method is best for you. I am also using second one in mine project.

Comment: i've used your second method on a few activities and it seems to work. though i put the isKill variable in the application so that it a global variable and all the activities can use it. i'll keep testing it and i'll let u know...

Comment: I am using second one, so hope this will helpful for u. plz accept answer if this helpful for u. So another user take the advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

When starting an activity that I don't want to be included in the BackStack I use:

```
myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

I have read (on here somewhere) about onBackPressed() not calling and instead they used onKeyPressed and specified the back button. I'll see if I can find the example.

Here is the example:
[Android - onBackPressed() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working/3558613#3558613)

Comment: but i do want to have activites in my stack. i do want to be able to go back to previous activities. i just want to clear the stack when the session expires and im on the loginActivity i should press back and the app should close

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setTitle("Exit");
   builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit? ");
   builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 // do something when the button is pressed
       public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

           finish();
       **YourActivityName**.super.finishAffinity();
    }
 })
 .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

// do something when the button is pressed
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
         }
  }).show();


}
```

Comment: **YourActivityName**.super.finishAffinity();   eg.,MyFirstActivity.super.finishAffinity();