# how can i clear the 3 activities from one activity

Tags: java, android

i have 3 activity (form 1 ,2 ,3 ) 
and after the user fill the form 3 and send it, i wanna delete the information from the activity (1 & 2 & 3 ) but AFTER SEND IT IN ACTIVITY 3

(i mean if the user after send it then click back i do not wanna him to find his information in form 1 & 2 & 3

```
.Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
 intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

does this let my 1 & 2 & 3  activity with no user data when he click back after activity 3 ?
can you please help me?
===================Edit===============

someone told me this but i do not get it , can you please help me how can  do it

```
pass a reference to the previous forms in the last one and call clear on any element
```

Thank you all

Comment: no that flag won't really help you, do you need to go back to 1, and 2 or can you just clear them form the stack?

Comment: if the user not yet press send in form 3 then i do not want to clear 1 &  2 but if he press send in form 3 then my app will move him to my home and i want to clear 1 & 2 & 3,how can i do it

Comment: check my 2nd approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428197/clean-stack-and-exit-app-onbackpressed/10428358#10428358

Comment: @Venky please engilsh i am not get it, Thanks

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava i do not have pressBackButton function,should i add it? or the permission is enough?i mean i wanna put just the premisson AM i right?

Comment: add activity pressBackButton method. this is activity override method

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava should i put it in all activities?also what should i put inside pressBackButton?

Comment: can you read my answer properly?. Whenever you want to close application then override the activity onBackPress() method and write the code which mention in my answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379134/finish-an-activity-from-another-activity/10379507#10379507

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava i do not wanna close the app, it is just clean the form,but the user still in the Home activity

Comment: Okay I understand. You can use static flag to identify form have been sent or not. After sending form successfully you can change the flag value and according to flag value reset the form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try this..

In your last sending activity,if you want to start another activity or existing activity, then add this

> finish();
>   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), new NewActivityOrExistingActivityName.class);
>   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>   startActivity(intent);

which will clear all the activities in your previous activity stack

Comment: also clear the data inside the activity 1 & 2 & 3 ? even if the user press Back Button?

Comment: my code `Intent i = new Intent(activity3.this, Home.class);     startActivity(i);` should i replace it with this `new Intent(getApplicationContext(), new NewActivityOrExistingActivityName.class);` or just add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(intent);` to my code?

Comment: just in between these two lines add i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: if the user press send, then my application will move user to Home page,but when he press back,my application go back to activity 3 with user information, this is my problem

Comment: i want after user press send in activity 3 , then act 1 & 2 & 3 will be clean, even if user press back

Comment: should i put it in activity 3 ? it will clean 1 & 2 & 3? if i put it in activity 3?

Comment: Ok then put 1 more line above the code finish(); this will finish your current activity then you call above code.. it will work

Comment: i do not get it, please can you edit your answer,so i can get it,Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10963/discussion-between-rashmi-and-maha)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code for solve your problem :

```
     Intent homeScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
     homeScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(homeScreen);
```

Thanks...!

Comment: yes please?becuase right now my sdk is not working and i should submit the code after 2 hours, so i need to be sure that my code is correct,Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onActivityResult method of Activity class like this:

In the activity 1, start activity 2 with this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And in the activity 1 override the onActivityResult method like this :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == 20) {
        // Activity 2 is finish, so finish activity 1
        finish();
    }
}
```

In activity 2, do this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and with this :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == 20) {
        // Activity 3 is finish, so finish activity 2
        setResult(20);
        finish();
    }
}
```

In activity 3, when the user submit your form use the code below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
setResult(20);
finish();
```

PS : I advice you to not use getApplicationContext() but rather "this" or "Activity1.this"

Cheers,
Sebastien

Comment: you mean if i finish fill activity 1 then move to 2 then i should finish activity1? i do not wanna that, WHAT I WANt:when the user press button send in  activity 3 , activity 1 & 2  & 3 will be finish,

Comment: No, I mean when you will finish activity 3, it calls onActivityResult method of activity 2 (which is still alive because you never call finish() method before) where you can call finish() method. This calls onActivityResult method of activity 1 where you can call finish() method. My answer do what you want : when you start your Home intent in activity 3, activity 1 & 2 & 3 will be finish.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, just tape "onActivi" then press ctrl+space (automatic indentation). Or just copy my code above in yours activities.

Comment: but i do not wanna to finish activity 1 & 2 until the user submit, is the code doing this?

Comment: Yes the code is doing this (of course if you don't call finish() method somewhere else). If you are on activity 2 and you want to modify some datas in activity 1, just press back button or apply return action on an another button and your activity 1 is still here.

Comment: so should i put onActivityResult with finish inside it in activity 1 & 2 & 3 even if i want to finish it after activity 3?

Comment: i tried it but when i press back button , it show me the information inside act 1 & 2 & 3 , should i call the onActivity or not?because i do literally your code

Comment: You have to put onActivityResult method in activity 1 and 2. I have edited my answer above with detailed code to put in each activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
There are two different ways to do that.
```

1. You can set result after finishing activities. This will work like chain. for example
              1->2->3
       suppose you are having finish button in activity 3 to send result to acitivity 1, then you can setResult() from activity 3 in finish button click event and finish your activity by calling finish().
     In activity 2 you can receive your data in onActivityResult() there you can check resultcode and save you data, like that you can do from activity 2 to activity 1 also, to send your result.

   setResult();
    onActivityResult();
2. for second method, first you have to set single top in your manifest file for your activity 1 in which you will finally return when you will save all your data from 3.

   ```
           android:launchMode="singleTop"

         from your activity 3 send broadcast to activity 1.
         to finish all your activity which you have opened after 1 you can use your code.


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
   ```

// THIS YOU NEED TO WRITE JUST BEFORE STARTING YOUR FIRST FORM ACTIVITY I THINK IN YOUR CASE JUST BEFORE STARTING ACTIVITY 1.

```
BroadcastReceiver form_filled = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String received_action = intent.getAction();

        if (received_action.equals("form_filled")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            // GET ALL DATA FROM BUNDLE.
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(form_filled, new IntentFilter("form_filled"));
```

// THIS YOU HAVE TO DO BEFORE FINISHING YOUR ACTIVITY 3

```
   Intent temp_intent = new Intent();
    temp_intent.setAction("form_filled");
    sendBroadcast(temp_intent);

 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
 class_obj_class_name class_obj = new class_obj_class_name(); // FILL YOUR DATA IN CLASS OBJ
 intent.putExtra("class_obj", class_obj); //class_obj IS YOUR CLASS OBJECT IN WHICH YOUR INFORMATION SAVED.
 startActivity(intent);

 // IN ACTIVITY 2 ONCREATE
 class_obj = (class_obj_class_name)intent.getSerializableExtra("class_obj");
 // SAME YOU CAN USE TO PASS DATA IN activity3
```

hope it will work..
    sorry for formatting... :)

Comment: can you please tell me please what is the code for send Broadcast that i should send it to activity 1 from activity 3, and how can i receive it in activity 1, and where should i put it ? inside on create or in another function

Comment: i am sorry for bothering you but i have all my data in class from act1 & 2 and i call it in act 3, so what it is the data that i should get it from bundle

Comment: when you move from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 save data and pass it to next activity. In this way you will have all your data in activity 3 then you can finish.

Comment: i put all data in class and call the object i do not pass data between the activitis it all in class, activity 1 & 2 fill the class and activity 3 call the object and show the user information that he fill it in 1 & 2, so how can i use your code

Comment: you want to display all your data in activity 3 to users

Answer (score 0):

```
.Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
 intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent)
```

Done :) 
Thank you ALL,

Comment: If it's work, you have to accept Rashmi or Dinesh answer who are both proposed to you the good code.