# onBackPressed() not being called

Tags: android

I have an activity "DashboardActivity" (not the main activity) where I want to trap the BACK button to ask if they want to log out (since BACK would normally take you to the login screen).

I have tried

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // ask if they want to logout.....
    logOutIfTheyReallyWantTo();

    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But testing this in the debugger it does not seem to hit the code at all.

I then tried to add

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

which also proves a waste of time.

Finally I tried

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // a long press of the call key.
        // do our work, returning true to consume it.  by
        // returning true, the framework knows an action has
        // been performed on the long press, so will set the
        // canceled flag for the following up event.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

but the debugger detects none of them.
LogCat only shows

```
    05-29 12:22:59.040: D/NetdConnector(14366): RCV <- {217 0}
    05-29 12:22:59.040: D/NetdConnector(14366): RSP <- {217 0}
    05-29 12:23:04.743: V/processReply(32759): sr0857000000
    05-29 12:23:07.673: W/KeyCharacterMap(32759): No keyboard for id 0
    05-29 12:23:07.673: W/KeyCharacterMap(32759): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    05-29 12:23:07.907: V/Dashboard(32759): Pause
    05-29 12:23:07.915: I/ComfortActivity(32759): start
    05-29 12:23:07.915: V/ComfortActivity(32759): Resume
    05-29 12:23:08.032: D/dalvikvm(14430): GC_EXPLICIT freed 92K, 52% free 3322K/6791K, external 5633K/7003K, paused 77ms
    05-29 12:23:08.329: I/DashboardActivity(32759): stop
    05-29 12:23:08.829: V/processReply(32759): sr0856000000
```

There seem to be many questions about this and I have tried the suggestions in all that i can find but no luck so far.

---- in response to question....

```
void logOutIfTheyReallyWantTo()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Log out?");
    alert.setMessage("Do you really want to log out?");

    //AlertDialog loginPrompt = alert.create();

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((ComfortApp) getApplicationContext()).soundClick();

            getComms().logout(true);
            Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ConfigurationActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // just like Perry the Platypus....
            // don't do much
            ((ComfortApp) getApplicationContext()).soundClick();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Silly question, but where are your logcat statements in your Java code?

Comment: try replacing return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
with "return false"

Comment: Please post the code to `logOutIfTheyReallyWantTo();` because I am cannot think of a reason why onBackPressed() isn't executing.

Comment: same Question has been asked here you can find answer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working/3558613#3558613

Comment: didn't bother with logcat - just put breakpoints - it doesn't hit any of them

Comment: Akki - sorry - didn't post it but I had that as well....

Answer (score 1):

Override `finish()` in activity to capture the exit. If you dont want to exit don't call `super`.

```
@Override
    public void finish()
    {
        if(!wantToExit)
        {
            super.finish();
        }
        else
        {
            logOutIfTheyReallyWantTo();
        }
    }
```

The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` on `Activity` is -

```
public void  onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Not trying to stop it exiting. I don't care if it exits. I just want to stop a particular screen transition from logged in to apparently logged out (but still logged in)

Comment: You can still capture the backpressed on `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try below code..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("Are you sure logout?");
        alertbox.setTitle("Logout");
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                showDialog(0);
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(DashBoard.this, Login.class));
                        DashBoard.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            }
        });
        alertbox.show();
    }
```

Comment: That is pretty much what the code does - but it never gets called.