# How to perform some action on background when the app exit

Tags: android

I have built an app that stores dates entered by the user in an array. Now I want to perform some action on the background of my app. In the background, I want a check that compares the current date of the device with the data stored in an array. When a match is found, I want to open a dialog. Is it possible to do some tasks in the background when the app exits?

Please help me with an example, I have no idea regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to do a pop up at certain date you don't need a service (that will just drain battery and be uncomfortable for users) but you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

You can find many examples here [AlarmManager Examples](https://www.google.it/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=alarm%20manager#hl=it&gs_nf=1&pq=android%20alarm%20manager&cp=23&gs_id=1o&xhr=t&q=android%20alarmmanager%20example&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=android%20alarm%20manager%20e&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=90a3455dfedf075f&biw=1920&bih=1075)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is use a Service.
For more information about that you can read documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

And a good tutorial is this:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Answer (score 0):

Override  `onKeyDown()` in Android 1.x or `onBackPressed()` in Android 2.x for handling Backpressed and you can start an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to  do some task in background when the app exit.

see android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

[for handling backpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working)

[Android - onBackPressed() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working)

Use [IntentSerice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for doing task in background  because as [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) says :

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.

Comment: U should override onPause() or onStop() instead, because if the user exit the app with the home button your code will never be executed...

Comment: @imrankhan Actually what i want is suppose my date store is 1-july-2012 12:30:00, after that i exit my app. Now when my current Date become 1-july-2012 12:30:00, i want to display a dialog. But at that time my app is not running.

Comment: You can use an AlarmManager intent as I suggested in may answer which you can set on the onStop() of your app.