# Control back button functionality

Tags: android, sms, hardware

From the given `ListView` in picture, I select the contact to send sms and move to another activity (second picture). And from this sms `Activity` picture. When I press back hardware button available on phone, I should move where I want. I don't want a default `Activity` to be displayed. How can I do this?

[image]
[image]

```
public class SendSms extends Activity{
ListView listView;
List<RowItems> rowItems;
CustomListViewAdapter adapter;

String toNumbers = "";
String separator;
int i=0,j,count=0,count1; String a[]=new String[5];
String number,val2;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.new4); 
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItems>();

val2=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null,   null);


 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
  String rawContactId =              cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                   // ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID
            }, ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { rawContactId }, null);
  if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String number = c.getString(0);
            //int type = c.getInt(1);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            int photoId = c.getInt(2);
            Bitmap bitmap = queryContactImage(photoId);
            RowItems p=new RowItems(bitmap, number, name);
            rowItems.add(p);

        } 
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.new5, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        c.close();
    }
}
    }
}


 private Bitmap queryContactImage(int imageDataRow) {
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
}, ContactsContract.Data._ID + "=?", new String[] {
    Integer.toString(imageDataRow)
}, null);
byte[] imageBytes = null;
if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        imageBytes = c.getBlob(0);
    }
    c.close();
}

if (imageBytes != null) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length); 
} else {
    return null;
  }
  } 
    public void showResult(View v) {
// String result = "";
String result1="";
    for (RowItems p : adapter.getBox()) {
      if (p.chck){
       // result += "\n" + p.getTitle();
        result1 +="\n" +p.getDesc();
        a[i]=p.getTitle();
        i++;
       count++;
      }
      count1=count; 
    } 

    Toast.makeText(this, result1+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }



       public void send(View v) throws IOException {
    int value=a.length-count1;
    for(j=0;j<a.length-value;j++){   
         if(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("Samsung")){   
                separator = ",";   
            } else   
                separator = ";";       


     number = a[j];   
    toNumbers= toNumbers +number +separator;   

}  

 toNumbers = toNumbers.substring(0, toNumbers.length());


    Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + toNumbers);

    String smsValue = "help iam in danger..i am presently at \n"+val2;
    if(val2==null){
        Toast.makeText(SendSms.this, "wait.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsValue);
    intent.setData(sendSmsTo);

    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: you didnt ask a question

Comment: i asked but its not edited properly so i am asking it here again

Comment: i want to control back button available on phone from the second picture..as there is not any different activity for it..so how to control it is a question for me

Comment: use onBackPressed() method.. check on it

Just call super.onBackPressed () or call finish() when activity ends

Comment: @Immanuel.I.George i don't have any different activity for sms..i am just passing intent for sms from listview activity..so where to place it is big question for me..

Comment: Can we see your code so we can better help you.

Comment: @Immanuel.I.George here is a code..

Comment: are you working on any chat app?

Comment: You should see and try the update answer below and @FunkTheMonk 's answer too!! It's better and more safe than a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should, when the `Activity` picture is displayed, try to call the `onBackPressed` method.

```
// back button pressed method
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
     // new intent to call an activity that you choose
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     // finish the activity picture
     this.finish();
}
```

If you don't want to call an external `Activity`, you can hide the layout calling by the `Intent` as below:

```
// back button pressed method
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
     // your layout with the picture is displayed, hide it
     if(MySecondView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            MySecondView.setVisibility(View.Gone);  
     // display the layout that you want
     MyDefaultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

As I said below, try with a **boolean** that you initialize to false at the beginning of your `Class`. When you start the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, make this boolean to true:

```
public class Foo extends Activity {
    private boolean isSms = false;
    // some stuff  

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    // ...
    startActivity(intent);  
    // make your boolean to true  
    isSms = true;  

    // create the onBackPressed method  
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          // check if the user is on the sms layout
          if(isSms)
              // do something  
          else
              // do something else like finish(); your activity

     }

 }
```

Or you can try to use the `onKeyDown` method (see here: [onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)) as below:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount()==0) {
        // dome some stuff
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can see the diffence between these two methods here: [onBackPressed() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558613/2668136) and on the website that I talk in the comments below.
Hope this will be useful.

---

**UPDATE:**
A better way should make an startActivityForResult to start the Intent.ACTION_VIEW:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And then, you return the cancel code like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode != 1 && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is @FunkTheMonk, just above, who tells the good choice!

Comment: i don't have any different activity for sms..i am just passing intent for sms from listview activity..so where to place it is big question for me..

Comment: Place it in your Activity, everywhere you want, see this: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html. Maybe you can know if your activity is displayed with a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Use startAtctivityForResult, and in onActivityResult check the resultCode. If it is Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED, the user 'backed out' of the SMS activity. Due to the implementation of the SMS activity being outside of your control, this might not be the only case when the result code says it has been cancelled.

Comment: The setResult will have to be called by the SMS activity which is outside of OPs control (based on his comments, I think he wants to use the device's SMS app to send the sms?). By default, pressing back will set the result to cancelled, so unless the SMS app does something unconventional it 'should' be ok

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to the class to handle device back button.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something
}
```

Please note that it requires API Level 5 or higher.

Comment: i don't have any different activity for sms..i am just passing intent for sms from listview activity..so where to place it is big question for me..

Comment: You have mentioned it as Second Activity in Question. But if you are having all the components in Same Activity, i would recommend to add this method to the activity and inside the method just hide the layout appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overide go back behaviour of hardware back button by calling a method name onbackpressed();

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
 // set intent to activity where you want to move on after back press
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 // also clean the current activity from stack.
 youractivityname.this.finish();
}
```