# How to work with onBackPressed() in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have Activity 'A', Activity 'B', Activity 'C', Activity 'D', Activity 'E', Activity 'E' . I want to exit the Activity click on onBackPressed(). When i run the app it goes to  Activity 'A' it does not exit the app. How can i implement with this.

Here is my Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout table_layout;
    EditText firstname_et, lastname_et;
    Button addmem_btn;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    ProgressDialog PD;
    ImageView imgButtonBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.performance_report);

        table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_PerformanceReport);


         //ImageView imgButtonBack;
         imgButtonBack = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagBackButton);
         imgButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Employee_List.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                //finish();
            }
        });


    }

}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alertbox.setTitle("Do you wish to exit ?");
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
               // finish used for destroyed activity
                finish();
            }
        });

        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // Nothing will be happened when clicked on no button 
                    // of Dialog     
          }
        });

        alertbox.show();
   }
}
```

Thanks to Appreciate.

Comment: Add to the Transaction this .. getFragmentManager().beginTransAction().add(.....,.....).addToBackStack().commit() this will cause to return to the last Transaction if its the first it will exit Hope it Helps

Comment: @Itzik Samara : thanks to reply , Sorry but i didn't get you .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - onBackPressed() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Which exits the application. And works fine for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

call `this.finish()` while you open your new activity(i.e going from activty A to some other activity). In your case write this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Employee_List.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
private exit = false;
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit)
        Home.this.finish();
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);

    }

}
```