# Programmatically simulate App being destroyed by OS from GUI button press

Tags: android, ondestroy

I would like to programmatically simulate my app being destroyed, for debugging. However for convenience, I would like this to happen by pressing a button on the app's GUI. At the moment, I have the following in a fragment:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.exitButton:
            Log.i(TAG, "Exit pressed");
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem is, `onDestroy()` never gets called. In fact, nor does `onPause()` either. (Or at least LogCat doesn't show the logs I write in them.) What am I doing wrong? (If I press the home button, `onPause()` does get called, so I don't think it's a problem with my `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` method

Thanks

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886790/1777090) if you want to exit app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MysticMagic's link, and the adding of `finish()`, The following finally worked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```