# onKeyDown call without user interaction

Tags: android, android-activity, back, onkeydown

i've an application in which I use the onKeyDown method in main activity to capture touch the back button and enter another activity. However at times the touch is captured without user interaction.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
**
* Start another activity
*/
  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class));

  return true;            
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Someone had same problem ?

Comment: why not you overriding onBackPressed() method of activity.

Comment: when-ever you want to call it just call onBackPressed() through code or press back button on device...

Comment: what's difference between onBackPressed() and onKeyDown() ?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558385/android-onbackpressed-not-working/3558613#3558613